# populating xml template at run time from object collection at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a xml template with is having Header and details section within it.
I have to populate the data into xml template at run time from a object collection. 
the details part will be repeating so i will be adding the details part to xml document in a foreach loop.
currently i am using xmldocument but i read that xmldocument occupies more memory and makes process slow on increasing size of xml file.
Please suggest me what is the best approach.

tempalte example

```
<Document>
  <Header>
    <OrgName></OrgName>
    <OrgAddress></OrgAddress>
  </Header>
  <Detail>
    <EmpId> </EmpId>
    <EmpName></EmpName>
    <Address>
      <Stree1></Stree1>
      <Stree2></Stree2>
      <Pin></Pin>
      <City></City>
    </Address>
  <Detail>
</Document>
```

Expected result

```
<Document>
  <Header>
   <OrgName>abc</OrgName>
   <OrgAddress>asd dfs 999 dfsd</OrgAddress>
  </Header>
  <Detail>
   <EmpId>100 </EmpId>
   <EmpName>Sham</EmpName>
   <Address>
       <Stree1>church street</Stree1>
       <Stree2>fgdf</Stree2>
       <Pin>5472</Pin>
       <City>Huston</City>
   </Address>
<Detail>
<Detail>
  <EmpId>112 </EmpId>
  <EmpName>Tomi</EmpName>
  <Address>
      <Stree1>fsdf</Stree1>
      <Stree2>fgdf</Stree2>
      <Pin>3455</Pin>
      <City>Huston</City>
  </Address>
<Detail>
<Detail>
 <EmpId>120 </EmpId>
  <EmpName>GhanSham</EmpName>
  <Address>
      <Stree1>sfssdf</Stree1>
      <Stree2>fgdf</Stree2>
      <Pin>6574</Pin>
      <City>Huston</City>
  </Address>
<Detail>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most memory efficient way to write Xml, then you should use XmlWriter class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx

Here is an example, using some of your Xml:

```
using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Document");
    writer.WriteStartElement("Header");

    writer.WriteStartElement("OrgName");
    writer.WriteString("abc");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("OrgAddress");
    writer.WriteString("asd dfs 999 dfsd");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    // End Header
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("Detail");

    writer.WriteStartElement("EmpId");
    writer.WriteString("100");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    // End Detail
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    // End Document
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Comment: I agree with you Mike, i have one problem here the xml structure get hardcoded here i want it to configured so that later i want to change positions of node or mark some nodes optional then i can configure it. using template i am able to edit template at anytime and change location of nodes.

Comment: Mike for overcoming the problem i mentioned in above comment i have used xslt. thanks